# Get path of script containing the calling function

Tags: python

Say I have two files, `foo.py` and `bar.py`. It does not matter where they are located, only that `foo.py` somehow manages to import `bar.py` and call a function `func()` defined in the latter. How would I get the absolute path of `foo.py` from `bar.func()`?

Comment: Could you pass it as a parameter to `bar.func(other_file)` or is that cheating?

Comment: The standard `inspect` module has functions to examine the call stack; given the function that called you, you can get the module that contains it; modules have a `__FILE__` attribute...

Comment: Of course foo.py might be in an egg or a zipped lib, or there might be a foo.pyc but no foo.py, or foo might even be created by custom importlib code, or … What do you want to happen in those cases? (The inspect module can sometimes do some nifty tricks to get the source code even when the file isn’t directly available, if that’s what you’re interested in.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "get the absolute path of `foo.py` from `bar.func()`". However, it's possible for a function to determine whose calling it at runtime by using `sys._getframe()` to reach back through the call stack and examine the calling function's globals (the variable `namespace` in the code below). Here's an example showing how to do that:

`foo.py`

```
import bar

bar.func()
```

`bar.py`

```
from pprint import pprint
import sys

def func():
    namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals
    pprint(namespace)
    print("caller's path:", namespace['__file__'])
```

Sample output:

```
{'__annotations__': {},
 '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>,
 '__cached__': None,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__file__': '\\Stack Overflow\\get-path-of-calling-script\\foo.py',
 '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0085A7D0>,
 '__name__': '__main__',
 '__package__': None,
 '__spec__': None,
 'bar': <module 'bar' from '\\Stack Overflow\\get-path-of-calling-script\\bar.py'>,
 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>}
caller's path: \Stack Overflow\get-path-of-calling-script\foo.py
```

See the `'__file__'` entry in the returned dictionary? It's the absolute path to the source file — `foo.py` — that contained the call made to `bar.func()`.

Comment: What else could *"get the absolute path of foo.py from bar.func()"* mean in the context of the question? Non-rethorical, I just want to know so that maybe I can rewrite the question in a clearer way.

Comment: bzzr: I wasn't sure if you meant when it was called (like my answer does) or perhaps determining it via some sort of static analysis. In other words, I didn't know how you wanted/expected to "get" the information. May I ask for what purpose you need/want this info?

Comment: I wanted to be able to refer to the calling script's path (really, *the path to the script containing the calling function*) independently of where the script was located, but I have since realized that wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In func, you can use inspect:

```
def func():
    stack = inspect.stack()
    calling_context = next(context for context in stack if context.filename != __file__)
    print(calling_context.filename)
```

Edited: I just saw jasonharper's comment that proposes the same solution. Read also abarnet's comment.

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute path, you can also try this:

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("foo.py"))
```